# Jupyter: magic %qtconsole console appears but does not work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, qtconsole, jupyter-console

Set up python on a new machine (mac air m2) and cannot for the life of my get my qtconsole back. Starting a jupyter notebook and running the magic in the cell causes the qt window to pop up, but no prompt is ever available (pictured below).  This used to work just fine and was invaluable for working with notebooks for exploring and iterating on commands before switching back to a cell.  It's driving me nuts.  Env information below.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTXd6.png)

---

> python version: Python 3.10.6

---

qtrelated:

> conda list | grep qt pyqt                      5.15.7
> py310h7aaa74b_3    conda-forge pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0
> py310h0f1eb42_3    conda-forge qt-main                   5.15.6
> h96bf0dc_0    conda-forge qtconsole                 5.4.3
> pypi_0    pypi qtpy                      2.3.1
> pypi_0    pypi

---

conda list | grep jupyter

> jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
> jupyter-console           6.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
> jupyter-contrib-core      0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
> jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.3                    pypi_0
> pypi jupyter_client            7.3.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0
> conda-forge jupyter_contrib_core      0.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0
> conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.7.0
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge jupyter_core              5.3.0
> py310hca03da5_0 jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.2.0
> py310hbe9552e_1005    conda-forge jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.6
> pyhd8ed1ab_1002    conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.6.1
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge jupyter_server            1.19.1
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge jupyterlab                3.4.7
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.7
> pypi_0    pypi jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge jupyterlab_server         2.15.2
> pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

Tried everything.  Can't get qtconsole to give me a prompt

Answer (score 1):

update: downgrading `jupyter-client` to version `6.1.12` solves this. thanks to ishigoya for the solution.                                               https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/519#issuecomment-1013822823

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).